# Pallet compilations of collectibles workshop fails due to non-existing branch

Tags: polkadot

On the first step after the prerequesites we are supposed to create a test pallet (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/collectibles-workshop/03-create-pallet/) ... for that we need to update the dependencies like so
[dependencies]
frame-support = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0"}
frame-system = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

but the thing is that there is no such branch polkadot-v1.0.0 . The only thing close to it that i found was a tag for the release polkadot-v1.1.0. But when i build the pallet I'm getting tons of compiler errors. e.g. error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'stdsimd'. Any ideas anyone how to build the test pallet. How did you do it?